# How to iCloud CoreData in TVOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tvos

I'm trying to implement coredata in iCloud in a App for Apple Tv, but when I try to use NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey in PersistentStoreCoordinator, this not exist in TVOS CoreData, how this link shows:
https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/releasenotes/General/tvOS90APIDiffs/Swift/CoreData.html

Can someonehelp me with this problem?

Comment: I upvoted your question because I've been struggling with this for the last 3 months and ended up with kludgy code that manually syncs and re-downloads data from CloudKit to a temporary SQLLite DB that keeps vanishing from the ATV.   I could find no good solution for app generated data that needs persistence when it is larger than the 500K available in userDefaults without creating a dependency on an internet connection and an iCloud account.

Comment: CK is slow, unreliable and requires an asynchronous app structure and distinct APIs from Core Data so I had a choice between maintaining a single code base and crippling my app by rewriting my iOS existing code to dumb it down to CK objects or find a way to auto sync the SQLLite database with iCloud.  I read in several forums that there is a way to make CoreData live with iCloud but the Apple documentation is clear as mud on this topic and comments on forums essentially show that it doesn't work.